# How to copy such bitmap to a DC?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, winsock, gdi

I'm writing a remote controlling program with GUI.
Here's a part of the server code:

```
HDC desktopHdc = GetDC(NULL);
int bm_x = GetDeviceCaps(desktopHdc, HORZRES);
int bm_y = GetDeviceCaps(desktopHdc, VERTRES);
DWORD bmSize = ((bm_x * 32 + 31) / 32) * bm_y * 4;
HDC memHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopHdc);
HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(desktopHdc, bm_x, bm_y);

while(TRUE)
{
    SelectObject(memHdc, (HGDIOBJ)bitmap);
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, bmSize);
    char* bmbits = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);
    BitBlt(memHdc, 0, 0, bm_x, bm_y, desktopHdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    GetBitmapBits(bitmap, bmSize, bmbits);

    int bytes = send(secondarySocket, bmbits, bmSize, 0);
    if(bytes == 0 || bytes == -1)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "disconnected", "", 0);
        break;
    }

    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

And here's some client code:

```
HDC windowHdc = GetDC(hwnd);
HDC memHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(windowHdc);
// bm_x and bm_y are sent by the server and received by the client
DWORD bmSize = ((bm_x * 32 + 31) / 32) * bm_y * 4;
while(TRUE)
{
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, bmSize);
    char* buf = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);
    int bytes = recv(mainSocket, buf, bmSize, 0);
    if(bytes == 0 || bytes == -1)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "disconnected", "", 0);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        buf[bytes] = '\0';

        HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(memHdc, bm_x, bm_y);

        SetBitmapBits(bmp, bmSize, buf);

        SelectObject(memHdc, bmp);
        BitBlt(windowHdc, 0, 0, bm_x, bm_y, memHdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // should copy received bitmap to the window DC
    }

    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);
}
```

I receive whole buffer in the client correctly. I make a bitmap from it. And then I just can't copy it to the window DC - nothing appears. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Here's my new code:

```
DWORD thServerSend(LPVOID param) 
{
    HDC memHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopHdc);
    HBITMAP bitmap;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        BITMAPINFO bmi;
        ZeroMemory(&bmi,sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
        bmi.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth=bm_x;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight=bm_y;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes=1;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount=32;

        char* bmbits;
        bitmap = CreateDIBSection(memHdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bmbits, NULL, 0);

        HBITMAP restore = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memHdc, (HGDIOBJ)bitmap);
        BitBlt(memHdc, 0, 0, bm_x, bm_y, desktopHdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        int bytes = send(secondarySocket, bmbits, bmSize, 0);
        if(bytes == 0 || bytes == -1)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "disconnected", "", 0);
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "bmsize: " << bmSize << " bytes: " << bytes << " bmbits: " << bmbits << std::endl; // for debugging

        SelectObject(memHdc, restore);
        DeleteObject(bitmap);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    DeleteDC(memHdc);
    DeleteObject(bitmap);

    shutdown(mainSocket, SD_BOTH);
    shutdown(secondarySocket, SD_BOTH);

    return 0;
}

DWORD thClient(LPVOID param) // window handle is passed through "param" parameter
{
    HDC windowHdc = GetDC((HWND)param);
    HDC memHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(windowHdc);
    HBITMAP restore;
    while(TRUE)
    {
        BITMAPINFO bmi;
        ZeroMemory(&bmi,sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
        bmi.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth=bm_x;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight=bm_y;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes=1;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount=32;

        char* buffer;
        HBITMAP bitmap = CreateDIBSection(windowHdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&buffer, NULL, 0);

        int bytes = recv(mainSocket, buffer, bmSize, 0);
        if(bytes == 0 || bytes == -1)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Disconnected.", "", 0);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            restore = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memHdc,bitmap);

            BitBlt(windowHdc, 0, 0, bm_x, bm_y, memHdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            std::cout << "bmsize: " << bmSize << " bytes: " << bytes << " bmbits: " << buffer << std::endl; // for debugging
            SelectObject(memHdc, restore);
        }
    }

DeleteDC(memHdc);
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Problem solved:

That is, how I called the threads:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thClient, (PVOID)&hwnd, 0, NULL);
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thServerSend, (PVOID)hwnd, 0, NULL);
```

As you can see, I used reference to the window handle in the argument of the thread calling function. This secretly caused stupid errors. Nobody could solve it without full code.

Comment: SelectObject returns a handle to the previously selected object.  You should select this object back into the dc when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a compatible bitmap.
Create a DIB section:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
BITMAPINFO bi;
ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bi.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.bmiHeader.biWidth=Width;
bi.bmiHeader.biHeight=Height;
bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes=1;
bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount=32;
char* buffer;
HBITMAP bitmap=CreateDIBSection(dc,&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS,&buffer,NULL,0);
// copy pixels to buffer
SelectObject(dc,bitmap);
BitBlt(....
```

Comment: Still no effects.
I also noticed, that I can write received bitmap to a file, but upside down.

Comment: Did you change to DIB on both server and client and removed the GlobalAlloc?

Comment: What do you mean by changing to DIB? Replacing GetBitmapBits() with GetDIBits()? And why remove GlobalAlloc()?

Comment: when you do CreateDIBSection, it creates the bitmap and allocates the pixels buffer and returns their address in the variable I named `buffer` in my code.  There's no need for further allocation.

Comment: Still same. I have updated my code in the main post. Could you look into it?

Comment: It looks generally ok.  How do you set bmSize? and what do the programs print?

Comment: This is the bmSize formula: ((bm_x * 32 + 31) / 32) * bm_y * 4.
This is what console prints (the server and the client have the same result): bmsize: 4096000, bytes: 4096000, bmbits: ╚đď.

Comment: Then I would suggest breaking the problem into sub problems and checking where the actual problem is.  Dump the buffer from the server into a file and see if you can open it with a viewer (IrfanView can open .raw images).  Then do the same with the received buffer from the network.  Hopefully it will help you resolve it.

Comment: I've found something: BitBlt returns false with error 6 in the client part.